# Fitting a USB C plug onto an laptop power adapter

Tags: power-supply

First post, be kind !

Bought a DELL laptop power adapter DL65195334 but want to put a USB C on the end of it.

1. Snipped off the connector , expecting to see 2 wires but saw 3 (BLack, Brown and white)
   the Black and Brown make 19.5V which is what I need.
2. Bought a USB to USBC cable and snipped off the usb end and connected the Red and Black (to Brown and Black)
3. This should have given me 19.5 volts to the USB-C but when I connect it to my laptop, it does not charge.

Questions

A. What is the 3rd white wire for in a Dell Power Supply
B> Why didn't it not work when I joined the black/brown & black/red to my USB cable - the usb cable had 4 wires (Red and BLack for Power) and then (green and white for data)

C. Anyone know how to get a USB C on the end of the power supply so I can power my Lenovo laptop ?, from a Dell power supply which has the correct outputs ?

Many thanks

TK

Comment: The third wire is a 1-wire protocol so the computer can talk to the charger and make sure that it's a GENUINE DELL POWER SUPPLY.  I.e. so that you have to buy it from Dell.

Comment: For the USB-C you need a microcontroller that can handle the USB-C power negotiation. Not just connecting cables.

Comment: Dell has his own standards and protocol, may be not compatible with another brand.

Comment: `This should have given me 19.5 volts` ... why do you not know what the output voltage is?

Comment: You're lucky your USB port isn't fried.

Comment: This should have given me 19.5 volts ... why do you not know what the output voltage is?
** I did know, I measured it with a volt meter, it was 19.5v  - just poor wording on my part **

Answer (score 3):

I can charge my phone at 9V run a Raspberry pi at 5V  or charge my laptop at 20V all using the same USB C power brick.

USB3.1 power delivery is very complicated it needs a special circuit in the charger that negotiates the voltage, and the powered device needs to ready itself too.

there are power delivery modules available. connecting one of them to your laptop charger may work

Answer (score 3):

A) The third wire communicates how powerful power supply is connected to laptop, i.e. how much power the laptop is allowed to draw.

B) By omitting the communication wire the laptop is not able to determine how much power it can take from power supply so it will not take any power at all.

C) You need to figure out how to tell to the Lenovo laptop that there is a power supply with some amount of power available. The protocol is just difrerent.

Do note that the modded charger with USB-C on Dell charger is now dangerous. It will give out 19.5V to all devices even if they have not requested 19.5V or even any charging voltage at all. It can destroy devices when plugged in. There is no point having such a USB-C killer cable around, someone might not know what it is and connect it somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

> A. What is the 3rd white wire for in a Dell Power Supply

Probablly to allow the laptop to identify what type of power adapter is plugged in. I don't know the precise details of DELL's system though.

> B> Why didn't it not work when I joined the black/brown & black/red to my USB cable - the usb cable had 4 wires (Red and BLack for Power) and then (green and white for data)

USB power delivery requires a negotiation process before the voltage is raised above 5V. So just dumping 19.5V on the line without negotiating first is not valid.

> C. Anyone know how to get a USB C on the end of the power supply so I can power my Lenovo laptop ?, from a Dell power supply which has the correct outputs ?

You can't, at least not in a reasonable manner, the USB power delivery protocol is non-trivial to implement and you need to be able to adjust the voltage of the power supply so you can start at 5V and then raise the voltage to what the device requested.

If you need a USB C power supply then you need to buy a USB C power suppply.

Comment: What a shame that my question has been classed as Off-Topic. However, I really appreciate all of your answers, which I would not have been able to find out otherwise. Thank You !!! - I have learned :-)  PS - Killer USB adapter going into the bin ! ;-)